# How to make Kerberos module

Tags: apache, kerberos

It is possible to make kerberos module for Apache server who is on windows? I understand that i need to make dll file from some source, but how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/

> Mod_auth_kerb is an Apache module designed to provide Kerberos authentication to the Apache web server. Using the Basic Auth mechanism, it retrieves a username/password pair from the browser and checks them against a Kerberos server as set up by your particular organization. The module also supports the Negotiate authentication method, which performs full Kerberos authentication based on ticket exchanges, and does not require users to insert their passwords to the browser. In order to use the Negotiate method you need a browser supporting it (currently standard IE6.0 or Mozilla with the negotiateauth extension).